# Difference between define and let w.r.t. syntax-rules keywords

Tags: macros, scheme, racket

I am a beginner in Racket as well as Lisp and was playing with syntax definitions. I defined a simple transformation like this:

```
(define-syntax hello
  (syntax-rules (in)
    ((_ name in world) (format "Hello ~a in ~a" name world))
    ((_ in name) (format "Hello ~a in here" name))))
```

Now, when I run it like these two cases, it works fine:

```
(hello "me" in "world") === "Hello me in world"
```

And,

```
(define in "inside")
(hello me in in)  === "Hello me in inside"
```

But, this results in an error,

```
(let ([in "Shire"])
  (hello "Martin" in in)) === Error: hello: bad syntax in: (hello "Martin" in in)
```

So, what is the reason for hello to fail here inside the let binding, whereas it works fine for a define? Also, where can I get more specific information regarding this difference? Thanks.

Comment: BTW, I just saw your question on #racket on IRC. You should definitely stick around for longer than 2 minutes. IRC is mostly a lurk-oriented medium; you get best results if you just post the actual question (without waiting for anyone to respond to a "can anybody help?" solicitation) and then wait 24 hours for a response. :-) (But, as you can tell, both lexi-lambda and I were able to answer here, so that worked out after all.)

Answer (score 5):

This has to do with the way syntax literals work. In particular, a syntax literal is considered matched if:

1. The literal does not have a binding at the point of macro definition, and also does not have a binding at the point of macro usage.
2. The literal has a binding at the point of macro definition, and also **has the same binding** at the point of macro usage.

The `define` case worked for you because you probably put the `define` in the same module as the macro. Which means that criterion 2 matched: `in` has the same binding at both macro definition and usage. But, if you defined the macro in one module (without the `define` for `in`), and defined the `in` in a different module where you are using the macro, things won't work so well. :-)

The `let` case creates a new binding for `in`. That will never match the binding for `in` at the top-level macro definition.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the `let` failed because of criteria 1, i.e. the the binding for `in` is present during the macro usage, but it was not present while defining the macro. But, I am still not clear about the `define` though, as this binding was also not present while defining the macro. I basically defined the macro in the Racket's editor, ran it, and then defined the `in` binding through `define` in the REPL. So second criterion should not match in this case. Or am I missing something?

Comment: And, also this scenario occurs when there's a global `define`. Having a `(define n "something")` inside a function and then calling `(hello "ok" in in)` also results in the same error.

Comment: As Alexis's answer explains, module-level `define`s affect everything in the module ("mutually recursive" was the wording she used, but still, same meaning), not just what comes after. As for internal `define` in a function, [those are transformed into `letrec`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/define.html#%28part._intdefs%29) and are not treated the same way as module-level `define`.

Comment: Correct, I re-read your answer after reading Alexis' answer and it made sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this is a little bit subtle—neither “should” work, but when the `define` is at the top level, it actually *alters* the interpretation of `syntax-rules`, which is where the behavior arises.

If you look at [the documentation for `syntax-rules`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stx-patterns.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fstxcase-scheme..rkt%29._syntax-rules%29%29), you’ll see that each *`literal-id`* is treated the same as in [`syntax-case`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stx-patterns.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fstxcase-scheme..rkt%29._syntax-case%29%29). The documentation notes that the literals are compared using `free-identifier=?`:

> An *`id`* that has the same binding as a *`literal-id`* matches a syntax object that is an identifier with the same binding in the sense of [`free-identifier=?`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxcmp.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._free-identifier~3d~3f%29%29).

This means that literals are matches as *bindings*, not as datums. That is, if you have a local definition of `in` in a `let`, it is a separate binding from the `in` marked as a literal within `syntax-rules`, so they will not match. Furthermore, identifiers introduced with `define` in a separate module will also not match.

Interestingly, if `in` is exported from the module that defines the macro, then imported using `rename-in`, the renamed binding will still work because Racket keeps track of renamings and considers them to be the *same binding* even if they are not the *same name*. These are orthogonal concepts, even if it’s sometimes easy to overlook all the nuances of that idea, but it’s somewhat intrinsic to hygiene.

Returning to the example in question, why does the following work?

```
(define-syntax hello
  (syntax-rules (in)
    ((_ name in world) (format "Hello ~a in ~a" name world))
    ((_ in name) (format "Hello ~a in here" name))))

(define in "inside")
(hello "me" in in)
```

Well, definition contexts are *mutually recursive*, so the definition of `in` after the macro definition is actually picked up by `syntax-rules`. Therefore, the `hello` macro actually expects the same binding as `in`, so the call works. If, however, `hello` is defined in a separate module from `in`, the macro call will *not* work because the bindings would be different:

```
(module hello racket
  (provide hello)
  (define-syntax hello
    (syntax-rules (in)
      ((_ name in world) (format "Hello ~a in ~a" name world))
      ((_ in name) (format "Hello ~a in here" name)))))

(require 'hello)

(define in "inside")
(hello "me" in in) ; => hello: bad syntax in: (hello "me" in in)
```

Comment: That explains it. Thanks!