# Collision with syntax-rules identfiers and global names

Tags: scheme

I have really edge case with `syntax-rules`. I'm trying to execute the `let-values` macro (it's from R7RS spec, but I've replaced string literals with identifiers):

```lisp
(define-syntax let-values
  (syntax-rules (bind mktmp)
    ((let-values (binding ...) body0 body1 ...)
     (let-values bind
       (binding ...) () (begin body0 body1 ...)))
    ((let-values bind () tmps body)
     (let tmps body))
    ((let-values bind ((b0 e0) binding ...) tmps body)
     (let-values mktmp b0 e0 () (binding ...) tmps body))
    ((let-values mktmp () e0 args bindings tmps body)
     (call-with-values
         (lambda () e0)
       (lambda args
         (let-values bind
           bindings tmps body))))
    ((let-values mktmp (a . b) e0 (arg ...) bindings (tmp ...) body)
     (let-values mktmp b e0 (arg ... x) bindings (tmp ... (a x)) body))
    ((let-values mktmp a e0 (arg ...) bindings (tmp ...) body)
     (call-with-values
         (lambda () e0)
       (lambda (arg ... . x)
         (let-values bind bindings (tmp ... (a x)) body))))))
```

Together with [SRFI-210](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-210/srfi-210.html) I have a collision between the `bind` identifier and function named `bind`:

```lisp
(define (bind obj . transducers)
  (apply bind/list (list obj) transducers))
```

To make SRFI-210 work with my [Scheme implementation](https://lips.js.org/) I've removed the check for the identifiers to not exist in scope. But it was a mistake. Since According to [Gauche syntax-rules docs](https://practical-scheme.net/gauche/man/gauche-refe/Hygienic-macros.html#Syntax_002drules-macro-transformer) this should not work:

```lisp
(define-syntax if+
  (syntax-rules (then else)
    [(_ test then expr1 else expr2) (if test expr1 expr2)]))

(let ((else #f))
  (if+ (even? x) then (/ x 2) else (/ (+ x 1) 2)))
```

This doesn't work in the Scheme implementation I've tested (Kawa, Guile, Chicken, Chez) it only works in Gambit.

So the question is how the `bind` symbol should work in the `let-value` hygienic macro when there is a global name `bind`?

I've tested this:

```lisp
(define else #f)
(let ((el_se #f) (x 10))
  (print (if+ (even? x) then (/ x 2) else (/ (+ x 1) 2))))
```

And it works for all tested implementations (ignoring Gambit where it works the same).

**EDIT**: I was looking at answer to this question: [Introducing a Named Variable with Syntax Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49987765/387194) with this quote from linked paper:

> Hygienic macros cannot expand in referentially-opaque
> code: if a macro expansion introduces a free identifier,
> the identifier refers to the binding occurrence which
> was in effect when the macro was defined rather than
> when the macro was expanded.

But this makes no difference in Scheme implementations I've tested.

```lisp
(define else #f)

(define-syntax if+
  (syntax-rules (then else)
    ((_ test then expr1 else expr2) (if test expr1 expr2))))

(let ((el_se #f) (x 10))
  (print (if+ (even? x) then (/ x 2) else (/ (+ x 1) 2))))
```

Comment: Did you find this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644555/difference-between-define-and-let-w-r-t-syntax-rules-keywords/

Comment: @Shawn this macro is from R7RS spec, so I guess it's the correct way of implementation. The link solves the question.

Comment: There's no definition of `let-values` in the copy of R7RS I'm looking at, just a description. You might be interested in [this one](https://scheme.com/tspl4/syntax.html#fullletvalues) from Dybvig's The Scheme Programming Language that doesn't use literals.

Comment: @Shawn page 70 https://small.r7rs.org/attachment/r7rs.pdf it only has string literals instead of identifiers.